# Cannot enable textbox, which leads to runtime error

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I am working on a ***VB6 legacy App*** (yes, very, very, very old app, migration is not an option). I have a `button` and a `textbox (VB.TextBox)`. The textbox is intially disabled (e.g. `Enabled = False)`. When I click on the `button`, the `textbox` should become enabled and get the focus.
This is the code for the OnClick event

```
Private Sub btnMAJ_Click(Index As Integer)

    txtNom.Enabled = True
    txtNom.SetFocus    

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I check the value of `txtNom.Enabled` inmediately after I change it to True, it is still False, and when the code reaches the line  `txtNom.SetFocus` it throws an error message

> Run-time error '5'
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument

because the `txtNom` control is still disabled. I don't understand what would be the problem.

This is a screenshot of the VB6 IDE with a watch on the value of `txtNom.Enabled` inmediatly after assigning **True**, you can see it is still **False**

[image: Screen capture of VB6]

Comment: Is there a `txtNom_Enter` event handler? If so, show the code for it.

Comment: Is that error 5 *on* the `SetFocus` line?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Yes, it's on the `SetFocus` line.
@TnTinMn, No, there is no event handler for `txtNom_Enter`

Comment: Although you've enabled the text control, if it is not visible (`txtNom.Visible` is `False`), then calling `SetFocus` on the control will throw this exception.

Comment: @MarkL the txtbox is visible. It is always visible from the start. It is just enabled or disabled according to the user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the problem here. In this particular scenario, the `txtNom` control was inside a `panel` that was also disabled. The control was not enabled until I specifically set **Enabled** to **True** on the containing `panel`. So it seems the `SetFocus` will fail if any of the containers of the component is disabled, which makes sense, but the error message information is something I think Microsoft should not be too proud of.

Comment: Yes, a better error message would have been "Cannot set focus at this time because `panel` container is disabled too."